# Proof by Contradiction relating to rational and irrational numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, proof-explanation

I've been given the question: given $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $x+y =\frac{m}{n}$, prove $x-y$ is irrational. I tried solving this using a proof by contradiction but I feel like I got a bit off base and I feel like I've screwed up somewhere.

> Proof by Contradiction
> $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$
> $x + y = \frac{m}{n}$, $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \neq 0 $
> $y = \frac{m}{n} - x$
> Assume $x-y$ is rational
>
> $x-y = \frac{p}{q}$, $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q \neq 0$
> $x - (\frac{m}{n} - x) = \frac{p}{q}$, using $y = \frac{m}{n} - x$
> $2x - \frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$
> $\frac{2xn-m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$
> $q(2xn-m) = pn$
> $2xn-m = \frac{pn}{q}$
> $2xn = \frac{pn}{q} + m$
> $x = \frac{(\frac{pn}{q} + m)}{2n}$
>
> $\therefore$ Contradiction as $x$ is irrational

Here is my working. Have I made any mistakes and is it okay to assume that since all the variables in the final fraction are integers that it is rational?

Comment: You could do a much shorter proof:  Assume $x-y$ is rational. Then, since $x+y$ is rational and $2x=(x+y)+(x-y)$, we have that $2x$ is rational and so $x$ is rational. Contradiction as $x$ is irrational.

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it, but it's a bit of a leap from where my train of thought was going so I think I will stick with a similar proof to my original one. Thank you though, I never would have thought of that, but maybe I will for future proofs now!

Comment: Your train of thought is going around the country just to travel 2 blocks. Add $x+y$ and $x-y$.

Comment: I understand that now, and the way shown by egreg below still follows the same thought pattern I was having but just the better way to rearrange it. I see how this method works and it is much faster than mine, but I wouldn't feel right claiming that as my answer because I never would have come to that on my own.

Comment: You should remove the image of your reasoning and instead format that as *text* and use MathJax for formatting. By posting an image you just made it completely impossible for a blind person to understand the question. Use images *only* for visual data.  BTW: for writing simple stuff like this you probably take less time just writing them as text instead of making a picture, cropping it and then uploading it...

Comment: Your question seems to read "If x+y is rational, then x-y is irrational". What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's correct. A bit too lengthy, though. From
$$
2x-\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q}
$$
you can derive
$$
2x=\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q}=\frac{mq+np}{nq}
$$
so
$$
x=\frac{mq+np}{2nq}
$$
would be rational, because you assumed $m,n,p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\ne0$ and $q\ne0$, so $mq+np\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $2nq\ne0$.

Comment: **Note:** Since $m,n,p,q$ are integers, we see that the top and bottom of the fraction of the right are integers, and we can see that the bottom is non-zero. So, $x$ would have to be rational, since it is the ratio of two such integers.

Comment: Fantastic. Not sure why I didn't see the way you showed in the first place. That's much more concise. Thank you very much. And also Omnomnomnom answered my second question, so thank you as well!

Comment: @Gallo I added Omnomnomnom's remark at the end. That's being quite picky, though. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Since $x+y$ is rational, if $x - y$ is rational, then so are $(x + y) - (x - y)$ and $(x + y) + (x - y)$

Comment: I downvoted, because this did nothing to support OP's attempts at his/her own proof. (Nor was the above a proof in any form).

Comment: When x = y = sqrt(2), then (x - y) = 0 and (x + y) - (x - y) is irrational.

Comment: @SometimesBlind do note that one of the premises was that "x + y" also be rational as well though, which wouldn't work for x = y = sqrt(2)

Comment: I respect the opinion of people downvoting the answer, though for future viewers of this post, note that my answer is correct.

Comment: Besides, the OP had his work in a link, and I think we agree here on MSE that work should be included in the post.

Comment: @AhmedHussein Only one of the two numbers you wrote is enough to conclude.

Comment: @user26857 true.

Comment: Thank you for informing me that my work should be included in a post. I wasn't sure how the formatting worked and thought it would just be easier to write it down instead, but I will learn how to do it properly for future posts.

Comment: @AhmedHussein I will remove downvote as you are correct about the work being in a link, and I jumped to conclusions, as the image automatically loaded for me. Plus this answer is of course helpful for future reference.

Comment: @Inazuma The answer was edited and didn't say this in the first version. Now it should be right and I removed the downvote.

Comment: @SometimesBlind it was always right. You simply misread the question. The edit was not done by me, it was done by someone who liked to emphasize the assumption in the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

From your "$2x -\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$, you should realize you have "twice an irrational is the sum of two rationals":  "$2x = \frac{p}{q} + \frac{m}{n}$.  The sum of two rationals is rational, twice an irrational is irrational, and you have your contradiction at your third line.